# Java - How to simulate one server with multiple clients that communicate through that server?

Tags: java, multithreading, windows-7

I am developing a little Java chat application that will run reliably on a small local area network.
I have Windows 7 installed in my machine (laptop).
I developed a server and a client that will represent (chat Messenger)

If the server runs, then any client can run and communicate with the server.
In the machine that runs the server, it can also run one client (client_1) to communicate with the server in the same machine.
If I want to run a second client (client_2) to communicate with client_1 through the server. Then I have to run it (client_2) in a another machine.

Is there a away to simulate two machines or two real clients that communicate with the server while using the same machine?

**Addendum:**
I only need this in the development stage. I just want to be able to develop and test in the same machine. But the final product will run as supposed to be, that is each client will run on a single machine. It is not a programming logic problem.

Comment: Relay the messages from client_1 to client_2. Or more generally, if you plan on having multiple clients (which presumably you do) relay each client message to **all** clients (including the sender). To do this, you will need to maintain a `Collection` of clients.

Comment: Multiple clients can connect to the server from single computer using different ports, that's how multiple browser tabs work, all you have to do is to assign different port number for different client. In one of my project I faced same problem, there firstly I searched for free port available on my computer for client socket and then I assigned that port to the client while creating instance of Socket. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution I can think: clients should open socket to the server with "localhost" as inet address. Then you can run multiple instance of them.

```
new Socket("localhost", port);
```

Comment: I know about this, but how to distinguish each one in the server side?. The server need to distinguish between them so that it can control the communication between them, that is each client must be unique.

Comment: You have IP address and port number of each client connected to the server to distinguish them.

Comment: Ok, so you need that clients have different IPs. I think your only chance will be to run some virtual machines. @SauravKumar: you're wrong, each client will have `127.0.0.1` address.

Comment: @FabioCarello I mentioned port number also along with the IP address, when multiple instances of same application is to be run on same computer then we need different port number for each of it's instance and on server we can get that port number to distinguish each client.

Answer (score -1):

Consider using VMWare, as you can configure multiple systems and virtual IPs within a single, logical, network of "computers".